Solving a differential equation with initial conditions using Laplace transforms
Problem:
Use the Laplace form to solve the following initial-value problem.
$$ y'' + 7y' + 10y = 4te^{-3t} $$
with the following initial conditions:
$$ y(0) = 0 $$
$$ y'(0) = -1 $$
Answer:
To solve this equation we take the Laplace transform of both sides. Note:
$$  \mathcal{L} \{ te^{-3t}  \} = \dfrac{1}{(s+3)^3} $$
\begin{align*}
s^2Y(s)  - sy(0) - y'(0) + 7(sY(s) - y(0))  + 10Y(s) &= \dfrac{4}{(s+3)^3} \\
s^2Y(s)  - (-1) + 7(sY(s) )  + 10Y(s) &= \dfrac{4}{(s+3)^3} \\
s^2Y(s)  + 1  + 7sY(s)  + 10Y(s) &= \dfrac{4}{(s+3)^2} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
(s^2 + 7s+10)Y(s)  &= \dfrac{4}{(s+3)^2} - 1 = \dfrac{4-(s+3)^3}{(s+3)^3} \\
(s^2 + 7s+10)Y(s)  &= \dfrac{4-(s+3)(s^2+6s+9)}{(s+3)^3} \\
(s^2 + 7s+10)Y(s)  &= \dfrac{4-s^3-6s^2-9s-3s^2-18s-27}{(s+3)^3} \\
(s^2 + 7s+10)Y(s)  &= \dfrac{-s^3-6s^2-9s-3s^2-18s-23}{(s+3)^3} \\
Y(s)  &=  \dfrac{  -s^3-6s^2-9s-3s^2-18s-23 }{ (s^2 + 7s+10) (s+3)^3 }
\end{align*}
Using an online inverse Laplace calculator, I find that:
$$ y = \left( -\dfrac{1}{2} \right) 
 e^{-3 t} (2 t^2 + 2 t + 3) + \dfrac{ e^{-5 t}}{2} + e^{-2 t} $$
The book's answer is:
$$ y = 2e^{-t}  - 3e^{-2t} + \cos t + 3 \sin t $$
Where did I go wrong?

Where did your textbook and your own understanding lead you?

The Laplace transform of $te^{-3t}$ is wrong. You should have had $(s+3)^2$ in the denominator instead of $(s+3)^3$.

Though, I did the calculations myself. As long as you didn’t copy the question wrong, the answer your provided is wrong as well. (For example, it does not even satisfy the initial condition $y’(0) = -1$.)
